# WPF: Dynamically change ListBox's ItemTemplate based on ListBox Items Size

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate, listboxitem

I need to change the DataTemplate of my ListBox, based on the ListBox items count. I have come up with the following XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
   <TextBlock Text="default template" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="OtherTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
   <TextBlock Text="other template" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>      
</Window.Resources>
<ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
  <ListBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
      <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count}" Value="1">
             <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource OtherTemplate}"/>
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
  </ListBox.Style>     
</ListBox>
```

With the above XAML, once I added two or more items to the bound list, the data template changed as expected (from other to default). However, if I remove the first item in the list with more than two items, the entire listbox just becomes empty (I verified that the bound list is non-empty). Removing the second item in a two items list works fine though (i.e. template changed from default to other).

Any ideas why this is happening? Or perhaps I went about the wrong way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

you could use data triggers, or you could use a `DataTemplateSelector` [Here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector) is an article that shows the basics.  and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) is the MSDN on applying it to the items control (also, a listbox)

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for the exact problem or the cause, but it is because a DataTrigger is setting a template when the count is 1 and only 1.

You can do 1 of 3 things to solve this problem, but only 1 I would recommend.

a) Implement your own DataTrigger by deriving from [System.Windows.TriggerBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.triggerbase.aspx)

b) Use an implementation of [System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that will convert from ItemsControl.Items.Count into a DataTemplate. Retrieve the templates by placing an element in scope of your resources as Binding.ConverterParameter, casting them to FrameWorkElement and call FrameWorkElement.FindResource().

C) This is my recommendation, write your own [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) to do the grunt work. This mechanism is specifically targeted at the functionality you with you achieve. I recently wrote one that will pick a DataTemplate based on the type of the source object without requiring a DataTemplate with no x:Key set. Using Properties on the template selector, you can pass DataTemplates into the DataTemplateSelector using XAML, removing that FindResource code 'todo' list.